# Nested variables in Jekyll Liquid

Tags: html, jekyll, liquid

I'm quite unexperienced with Jekyll and I'd need your help.

I'm trying to optimize the following piece of code:

```
<a href="{{ "/assets/img/image.jpg" | prepend: site.baseurl }}" title="a">
  <picture>
    <source type="image/webp" srcset="{{ "/assets/img/image.webp" | prepend: site.baseurl }}">   
    <source type="image/jpeg" srcset="{{ "/assets/img/image.jpg" | prepend: site.baseurl }}"> 
    <img src="{{ "/assets/img/image.jpg" | prepend: site.baseurl }}" alt="a">
  </picture>
</a>
```

What I'd like to do is to see if I can optimize this. For instance, I don't find the way to put the `/assets/img/image.jpg` inside a Liquid variable and then call it via the `href`, `src`, `srcset` parameters. I suppose it's possible though.

Would you have any tips? :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Two things you could do.

**Assign two variables**

```
{% assign jpg = "/assets/img/image.jpg" | prepend: site.baseurl %}
{% assign webp = "/assets/img/image.webp" | prepend: site.baseurl %}

<a href="{{ jpg }}" title="a">
  <picture>
    <source type="image/webp" srcset="{{ webp }}">   
    <source type="image/jpeg" srcset="{{ jpg }}"> 
    <img src="{{ jpg }}" alt="a">
  </picture>
</a>
```

or

**Use include and pass the image path as a parameter**

`image.html`:

```
<a href="{{ include.path | append: ".jpg" | prepend: site.baseurl }}" title="a">
  <picture>
    <source type="image/webp" srcset="{{ include.path | append: ".webp" | prepend: site.baseurl }}">   
    <source type="image/jpeg" srcset="{{ include.path | append: ".jpg" | prepend: site.baseurl }}"> 
    <img src="{{ include.path | append: ".jpg" | prepend: site.baseurl }}" alt="a">
  </picture>
</a>
```

Where needed, you would then insert the html above by:

```
{% include image.html path="/assets/img/image" %}
```